# jQuery.calendarPicker date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm trying to use the [jQuery.calendarPicker](http://bugsvoice.com/applications/bugsVoice/site/test/calendarPickerDemo.jsp) on a site of mine using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var calendarPicker2 = $("#wedding_date_picker").calendarPicker({
  showDayArrows: false,
  callback:function(cal) {
    console.log(cal.currentDate);
  }
});
</script>
```

Which I've managed to get working, and is logging something along the lines of:

```
Date {Wed Aug 21 2013 16:12:19 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)}
```

What I want to do now, however, is take this date and insert it into a hidden input field after I've formatted it to yyyy-mm-dd... the problem is I don't know how to do the formatting.

Can someone help? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS function `Date.format` like this:

```
var formattedDate = cal.currentDate.format("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't work: `"cal.currentDate.format is not a function"`

Comment: Then you should probably translate it into Date object: new Date(cal.currentDate).format("yyyy-mm-dd")

Comment: Nope, sorry - doesn't work. Are you sure you're not using a library or something which provides the .format() method?

Comment: It's basic JS function used with Date objects. You could try using var now = new Date(); now.format("m/dd/yy"); for testing.

Answer (score 0):

from the jquery UI manual:

```
//setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

a full list of the avalible date formats can be found here:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't planning on using jQueryUI.